# How to call many remote WCF service from one central WCF service using Async call?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, asynchronous

Simple Scenario:

- Client makes a AJAX Sync call to a central WCF server ==> url: "svc/About.svc/GetAboutInfo";
- The WCF "GetAboutInfo()" will call "GetSiteInfo()" in 80 remote servers;
- I get the results but it takes awhile since these are NOT Async calls;
- With that in mind I have 2 things to fix (but I don't know how):

  1 - make GetSiteInfo() a Async call;

  2 - only return GetAboutInfo() to the client after ALL Async calls from GetSiteInfo() are returned;

Note: I cannot use "Tasks" since we are still on .Net 3.5.
Currently I am researching about IAsyncResult (with Begin/End methods) but could not find anything that would allow me to adapt to my current code below.
(I am calling remote servers from a central WCF in a loop).

Bear in mind the WCF below is identical in all remote servers except that the loop which only exists in the "CENTRAL WCF server"(the WCF that calls the remote servers). Here is the partial WCF code:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IAbout
    {
      [OperationContract(Name = "About_GetAboutInfo")]
      [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetAboutInfo", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
      About.AboutInfo GetAboutInfo();

      [OperationContract(Name = "About_GetSiteInfo")]
      [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetSiteInfo", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
      About.SiteInfo GetSiteInfo();
    }


      public SiteInfo GetSiteInfo()
      {
        SiteInfo siteInfo = new SiteInfo();
        //...code stripped out...
        return (siteInfo);
      }

      public AboutInfo GetAboutInfo()
      {
          AboutInfo aboutInfo = new AboutInfo();

          SiteInfo siteInfo = new SiteInfo()
          {
             ID                = site.ID
            ,Name              = site.Name
            ,DatabaseVersion   = "Unavailable"
          };

          foreach (Site site in sites)
          {
            try
            {
              string uri = Utilities.CombineUri(site.Uri, "svc/About.svc/ws");
              AboutServiceClient wcfClient = new AboutServiceClient("About");
              wcfClient.Endpoint.Address   = new EndpointAddress(uri);
              SiteInfo childSiteInfo       = wcfClient.GetSiteInfo();  <== call is blocked here until I get a response from remote server
              siteInfo.DatabaseVersion     = childSiteInfo.DatabaseVersion;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { //...code stripped out... }

            aboutInfo.Sites.Add(siteInfo); <== this should only be returned after we receive response from all calls
      }

...

    public class AboutServiceClient : ClientBase<IAbout>
    {
      public AboutServiceClient(Binding Binding, EndpointAddress Address) : base(Binding, Address)
      {
        if (Binding is WebHttpBinding)
        {
          this.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
        }
      }

      public AboutServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : base(endpointConfigurationName)
      { }

      public About.SiteInfo GetSiteInfo()
      { return base.Channel.GetSiteInfo(); }

      public About.AboutInfo GetAboutInfo()
      { return base.Channel.GetAboutInfo(); }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have the servers update a central repository themselves?  Or is this a demand type scenario?

Comment: demand scenario. We rely on the "Central" server to communicate with all remote servers. Data is constantly changing in the database. The web service described here could be changed to update a repository since the ABOUT data is static but all our other WCF services pull dynamic data using filters so we need to fetch it in the remote servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the "Task Parallel Library for .NET 3.5" from NuGEt and use tasks that way. Then you can wrap you `wcfClient.GetSiteInfoBegin` and `wcfClient.EndSiteInfoBegin` methods with [Task.Factory.FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This is untested, but maybe something like this:

```
public AboutInfo GetAboutInfo()
{
 AboutInfo aboutInfo = new AboutInfo();

 SiteInfo siteInfo = new SiteInfo()
 {
    ID                = site.ID
   ,Name              = site.Name
   ,DatabaseVersion   = "Unavailable"
 };

  var tasks = new List<Task<SiteInfo>>();
 foreach (Site site in sites)
 {
   try
   {
     string uri = Utilities.CombineUri(site.Uri, "svc/About.svc/ws");
     AboutServiceClient wcfClient = new AboutServiceClient("About");
     wcfClient.Endpoint.Address   = new EndpointAddress(uri);
      tasks.Add(Task<SiteInfo>.Factory.FromAsync(wcfClient.GetSiteInfoBegin, wcfClient.EndSiteInfoBegin, null)
       .ContinueWith(t =>
       {                    
            siteInfo.DatabaseVersion = t.Result.DatabaseVersion.DatabaseVersion;
       }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()));

   }
   catch (Exception e)
   { //...code stripped out... 
    }
}

Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray()).ContinueWith
    ( ts =>
    {
        ts.ForEach( t => aboutInfo.Sites.Add(t.Rrsult); 
    });

return aboutInfo;
```

}

Comment: Ned, I will mark this as the answer because first: I didn't know I could download Tasks from Nuget and second because of the awesome sample code. We will certainly try that. We did some tests using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem and MaunalResetEvent class and it also worked like a charm! -- thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Using .NET 3.5 is a major restrain. You won't be able to keep your linear code flow. Here's the new workflow:

- You'd need to implement `BeginGetAboutInfo`/`EndGetAboutInfo` as described in ["How to: Implement an Asynchronous Service Operation"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731177%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).
- In `BeginGetAboutInfo` you'd do start 80 asynchronous requests to the remote WCF service with `wcfClient.GetSiteInfoBegin` (in parallel) and keep track of `IAsyncResult` of each.
- As these asynchronous operation are completing (your callback will be called for each), use `wcfClient.EndSiteInfoBegin` to retriever and store the result of each operation.
- As soon as all of them have completed, invoke the callback, provided by the client when your `BeginGetAboutInfo` was called.
- Now expect the client to call your `EndGetAboutInfo`, where you'd provide the combined result of all 80 operations.